# bootstrap: how to switch "pages" without reloading bootstrap (jquery-mobile style)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile, navigationcontroller

assuming there is a lot of truth behind the claim that Bootstrap cannot be used together with JQuery UI and JQuery Mobile (unless you try some 3rd party hybrid projects that only aim to breed the two together for specific versions), what is the best way to do a mobile navigationController-style UI with bootstrap?

example:
the main page is a list of items, each, when tapped, slides the view to the left, opening a new page (without reloading all core libraries such as BS itself and its dependencies) with a "back" button at the top, and so on?